# Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Then for all $x \in X$, the set $\{x\}$ is closed. Moreover, every finite subset of $X$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Then $\forall x \in X$, the set $\lbrace x\rbrace$ is closed. Moreover, every finite subset of $X$ is closed.

I am having a hard time doing this one, can someone help me on this? How should I proceed?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The complementary of $\{x\}$ is open, if $x\neq y$, there exists $U,V$ open such that $U\cap V$ is empty and $x\in U, y\in V$ implies that $V$ is included in the complementary of $\{x\}$. Finite union of closed sets are closed implies the second assertion.